# Rotation of a Vector around a point in 3D space with specific x,y&z angles [JAVA]

Tags: java, math, vector, multidimensional-array, 3d

for my playermodel i have several bodyparts at specific positions like this:
the right arm at [-2, 2 ,0]  and the second part of the arm is located at [-2, 6,  0]
Now i want to rotate the first part of the arm and want the second part of the arm at the end of the first part.
I have already got something working for it with mycode, but the point is not always translated to the correct position.

This is what i have so far:

```
public static Vector3d rotateVectorAroundOrigin(Vector3d angle, Vector3f origin, Vector3f point) {
    double radius = Math.sqrt(((point.x - origin.x) * (point.x - origin.x))
            + ((point.y - origin.y) * (point.y - origin.y)) + ((point.z - origin.z) * (point.z - origin.z)));

    double newX = origin.x + (radius * (Math.sin(angle.z) * Math.sin(angle.y)));
    double newY = origin.y + (radius * Math.cos(angle.x));
    double newZ = origin.z + (radius * Math.sin(angle.y) * Math.cos(angle.y) * Math.sin(angle.z));

    return new Vector3d(newX, newY, newZ);
}
```

Hope somebody can help me

Comment: Writing answer right now in paint, I wouldn't be able to necessarily do the actual code but I can explain the concept.

Comment: Okay - great im not the best at math so...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure the math you are using in your equations, so I just figured it out the way I was taught for converting from a vector magnitude and angle into a point. The equation you are looking for for the final point is: `P_f = new double {4cos(angle) + x_0, 4sin(angle) + y_0, z_0}`

Please note that this **only works rotating in one direction**. In other words, it will only work for rotation in the xy-plane, not a rotation from the z-plane. This is because for a rotation in multiple planes, you will **need an angle in each plane**.

**Reference**

[image: First]

**Equation for second point**

[image: Second]

**Example of angles in 3-D**

[image: Third]

Comment: Eww- i need it for 3D

Comment: Thought so, this will work for 3-D but it is just for one direction. If you want more than one direction, just swap the plane and what variable you are changing, i.e. if you are in the xz plane, use `(4cos(omega) + x_0, y_0, z_0 + 4sin(omega))`, where omega is another angle of rotation.

Comment: What u mean with 4cos?

Comment: In a mathematical sense, I did. Just in a computer science sense, I believe in java it is like `4 * cos(angle)`

Comment: Why is it 4 times cos and not just cos?

Comment: Because the radius is 4, if we just had cosign it would mean it would be a radius of one, but in your picture with points [-2, 2, 0] and [-2, 6, 0] that is a radius of four.

Comment: Sorry, it is two angles I suppose, my bad, updated with explanation.